# SD card seems to be empty and write protected

Tags: sd-card

When I plug my SD card which has some video into my computer, it says that the SD card has 7.06/14.8Gb left. But when  I opened it, there were only two folders which is DCIM and MISC. Inside DCIM there are some files that seems to be system files. No hidden files either. The size of the two folders combined is only 32kb. The card was also write protected and I don't know why.

Is my SD card still recoverable? And how to recover it? I have many important pictures in it.

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: @malakrsnaslava edited. .___."

Comment: Windows, Mac, Linux? I will asume that you are on Windows. Have you tried using recuva? (https://www.piriform.com/recuva
)

Comment: Windows, I will try it.

Comment: What function should I use??

Comment: If you want to recover pictures than pictures. But also see if your card is locked by side switch and than revocer any corupted data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19276/discussion-between-malakrsnaslava-and-santi-santichaivekin).

Answer (score 0):

The sd card propperly have a littel switch on the side, try change the state of that switch.

This youtube video shows how to do it: [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R40ROF7nJ2I)

Answer (score 0):

I had an SD card which kept reporting "write-protected" on Windows XP using the exFat file system. When I tried it on Windows 7, a box pop up to "Scan and repair the disk". After doing that, the disk worked (ie. was not "write-protected") on Windows XP. May not be related to your problem, hope its helpful.